# Why doesn't IconTheme resource path get listed on get_search_path

Tags: c++, gtkmm3

On GTKMM reference docs for Gtk::IconTheme the section for add_resource_path() says

> **void Gtk::IconTheme::add_resource_path  (   const** std::string **&     path    )**
>
> Adds a resource path that will be looked at when looking for icons,
>   similar to search paths.
>
> This function should be used to make application-specific icons
>   available as part of the icon theme.
>
> The resources are considered as part of the hicolor icon theme and
>   must be located in subdirectories that are defined in the hicolor icon
>   theme, such as @a path/16x16/actions/run.png. Icons that are directly
>   placed in the resource path instead of a subdirectory are also
>   considered as ultimate fallback.
>
> **Since gtkmm 3.14:**
>
> **Parameters**
>
> **path** A resource path.

I created a variable for that and below is my sample code:

```cpp
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::IconTheme> window_icon_theme = Gtk::IconTheme::create();
window_icon_theme->add_resource_path("/home/keyikedalube/Source/basic-calc/icons")

// get the path lists
std::vector<Glib::ustring> path_lists = window_icon_theme->get_search_path();
for (auto i : path_lists)
        std::cout << i << endl;
```

The output yields:

```
/home/keyikedalube/.local/share/icons
/home/keyikedalube/.icons
/usr/share/xfce4/icons
/home/keyikedalube/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share/icons
/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/icons
/usr/local/share/icons
/usr/share/icons
/usr/share/icons
/usr/share/xfce4/pixmaps
/home/keyikedalube/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share/pixmaps
/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/pixmaps
/usr/local/share/pixmaps
/usr/share/pixmaps
/usr/share/pixmaps
```

My resource path `/home/keyikedalube/Source/basic-calc/icons` doesn't show up in the list

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APIs that refer to "resource" paths are talking about paths inside of [GResources](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GResource.html) not paths on the filesystem.